# nth highest salary using subquery and dense_rank doesn't match when table has duplicate salaries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by, sql-limit

I was trying to get nth highest salary from table using subquery and dense_rank method.
below are the results for each method.

**Subquery Method:**

```
select Top 1 Salary 
from (
    select top 7 Salary from Employee order by Salary desc
) as Result
order by Salary
```

This method returns 7th highest salary as: 3000

**Dense_Rank Method:**

```
select * 
from (
    select Salary, DENSE_RANK() Over(order by Salary desc) DRank 
    from Employee
) as Result 
where DRank=7
```

This method returns 7th highest salary as: 1000

**Initial Table data:**

[image: Employee Table]

Can anyone give me an idea about which method is correct and why?

Comment: `Top N` counts duplicates as separate values unlike `DENSE_RANK`. Use `ROW_NUMBER` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DENSE_RANK()` does not do what you want. It assigns incremental numbers *while giving the same rank to ties*. So there could be more than 6 records with a higher salary than the records ranked 7th.

The other query gives you the correct result, but could be simplified by using the `OFFSET/FETCH` syntax, which is available in SQL Server since version 2012:

```
select * from employee order by salary offset 6 rows fetch next 1 row only
```

Comment: I am getting error: _Incorrect syntax near '1'. Expecting ID._ while executing above query.

Comment: @KashinathRaut: my bad, it was missing the `next` keyword. Fixed.